# Ignoring file "path", missing required architecture i386/armv7 in file "path"

Tags: ios, iphone, armv7, i386, foxitembeddedsdk

I have the foxit embedded sdk for iPhone. It has demo apps and I wanted to see the output of the demo apps.

There are few steps like, copying header files and adding two ".a" files into "include" and "bin" folder respectively. Few days back when demo apps were tested in simulator, it was working fine. But now when I run the demo apps for both iOS 6 and 7, it doesn't load the pdf and it gives me few warnings including the ones mentioned below :

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/xyz/Downloads/FoxitEmbeddedSDKforiOS2.1.23354.1092.101412.0904_enu/examples/demos/bin/libfpdfemb_ios_arm.a, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/xyz/Downloads/FoxitEmbeddedSDKforiOS2.1.23354.1092.101412.0904_enu/examples/demos/bin/libfpdfemb_ios_arm.a (3 slices)

/Users/xyz/Downloads/FoxitEmbeddedSDKforiOS2.1.23354.1092.101412.0904_enu/examples/demos/demo_view_scrolling/Classes/PDFView.mm:18:41: Instance method '-getPDFPage:' not found (return type defaults to 'id').
```

I came accross an answer, that it cannot be run on simulator and by using "lipo" command one can create universal library. But since this a third party how can I achieve this. And when tested on device with iOS 7 also gives warning mentioned below:

```
 ignoring file /Users/ramani/Downloads/FoxitEmbeddedSDKforiOS2.1.23354.1092.101412.0904_enu/examples/demos/bin/libfpdfemb_ios_arm.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/ramani/Downloads/FoxitEmbeddedSDKforiOS2.1.23354.1092.101412.0904_enu/examples/demos/bin/libfpdfemb_ios_arm.a (3 slices)
```

and another warning as above for another ".a" file "libfpdfemb_ios_emu.a", when app is run in device(iOS 7).( this extra warning is only in device).

I have no clue what went wrong.

The apps are sample apps which came along with the foxit embedded sdk, so i haven't changed any code.
It was even working on the simulator earlier.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.